# Why is there a carbon atom without a greek letter in protein residues?

Tags: molecular-biology, terminology

For protein residues I know that $C\alpha$ denotes the first carbon atom attached to a functional group. Each subsequent carbon is given a corresponding greek letter ($\beta, \gamma, \delta$) except for one. For example, each residue in a PDB file has a list of atoms that looks something like this:

- ATOM     32  N  AARG
- ATOM     33  CA AARG
- ATOM     34  C  AARG
- ATOM     35  O  AARG
- ATOM     36  CB AARG
- ATOM     37  CG AARG
- ATOM     38  CD AARG

(A,B,G,D are stand-ins for the greek letters). Why is there just a plain C in this list? What is significant about that carbon?

Answer (score 1):

In your context, the "plain-C" labelled carbon is the carbon atom in the carbonyl ($\ce{C=O}$) group.
In organic chemistry, the [alpha carbon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_and_beta_carbon) is the carbon immediately adjacent to a functional group. In general, the greek letters in alphabetical order denote the distance in increasing order from a functional group.  The $\ce{C_\alpha}$ in the case of amino acids is alpha carbon with respect to both the amine and carbonyl.

[image]

Comment: The edit seems to have spoiled your answer. I imagine you can easily edit it to fit the new question that does not mention the phantom C'.

Comment: @David Done....